# ¿Cómo asignar el valor del siguiente renglón un pandas dataframe el valor del renglón inferior con if else?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bucles

Tengo el siguiente dataframe de pandas:

```
0       nan
1    0.0000
2    0.0027
3    0.0023
4   -0.0002
5    0.0016
6    0.0000
7   -0.0061
8   -0.0025
9    0.0002
```

y deseo obtener la siguiente columna:

```
0    1.0000
1    1.0000
2    1.0000
3    1.0000
4   -1.0000
5    1.0000
6    1.0000
7   -1.0000
8   -1.0000
9    1.0000
```

La mejor forma que he encontrado es

```
df['a'].apply(lambda x: abs(x)/x if x != 0 else 0)
```

Pero esa fúnción produce la siguiente columna:

```
0    nan
1    0.0000
2    1.0000
3    1.0000
4   -1.0000
5    1.0000
6    0.0000
7   -1.0000
8   -1.0000
9    1.0000
```

Como podran ver, quiero asignarle al primer renglón el valor del segundo renglón (o el del siguiente si el renglón inferior tiene el valor de 0). Y cuando el valor sea 0 (como en la posición 1 y 6), necesito agregar el siguiente valor calculado con la operación abs(x)/x.  Quisiera saber como modifico el condicional para lograr estas dos condiciones, o cualquier otra forma que me puedan sugerir de manera recursiva.

Comment: En la fila 6 de la salida que deseas obtener, ¿no debería haber un -1? Ya que la fila 7 es negativa...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma relativamente sencilla que se me ocurre, para no tener que iterar por las filas, es la siguiente:

1. Convertir cada dato en 1.0 o -1.0 usando `np.sign`, pues eso es equivalente a `abs(x)/x` (así no necesitas inventar la `lambda` que hace lo mismo)
2. Asignar en el resultado `np.nan` a cada celda de valor cero
3. Usar `.fillna(method="bfill")` para rellenar todos los `NaN` con el valor de la siguiente fila no-nan.

Es decir, partiendo de tu dataframe:

```
>>> print(df)
        a
0     NaN
1  0.0000
2  0.0027
3  0.0023
4 -0.0002
5  0.0016
6  0.0000
7 -0.0061
8 -0.0025
9  0.0002
```

Hacemos:

```
import numpy as np

df.a = df.a.apply(np.sign)
df.a[df.a==0] = np.nan
df = df.fillna(method='bfill')
print(df)
```

---

```
     a
0  1.0
1  1.0
2  1.0
3  1.0
4 -1.0
5  1.0
6 -1.0
7 -1.0
8 -1.0
9  1.0
```

### Actualización

Según entiendo del comentario hecho por el usuario, en realidad cada cero debería rellenarse con el valor *anterior* distinto de cero, y no con el siguiente, salvo para los ceros iniciales para los que no hay valor anterior por ser los primeros. Para ellos se rellena con el *posterior* distinto de cero.

Por suerte esto también es bastante sencillo de lograr. Primero haces un `fillna()` con el método "ffill", que dejará los primeros `NaN` sin tocar, al no tener valor previo por el que cambiarlos, pero rellenará todos los demás. Y después vuelves a hacer un `fillna()` con el metodo "bfill", que te rellenará los valores iniciales.

O sea:

```
import numpy as np

df.a = df.a.apply(np.sign)
df.a[df.a==0] = np.nan
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
df = df.fillna(method="bfill")
print(df)
```

---

```
     a
0  1.0
1  1.0
2  1.0
3  1.0
4 -1.0
5  1.0
6  1.0
7 -1.0
8 -1.0
9  1.0
```

Comment: Mil gracias! me sirve esa solución.

Comment: Mil gracias por la respuesta y me parece muy útil. El asunto es que, en la primera parte sería con un bfill, pues tomaría el valor siguiente en la columna (en mi ejemplo posiciones (0 y 1) , eso para arrancar la secuencia de la columna. Pero en los siguientes campos en donde haya un 0 (como en la posición 6), debería tomar el valor de la fila anterior, por lo que el método a utilizar es ffill como método de relleno.  La razón detrás de este raciocinio, es una teoría que replico en un estudio que hago en el momento.

Comment: Ahora no te entiendo... ¿dices que los ceros deben cambiarse por la anterior fila no-cero, salvo por los primeros que deben ser por la posterior? ¿Y los NaN? ¿Se tratarían como los ceros? Eso explicaría por qué en tu fila 6 habías puesto 1.0 en vez de -1.0, pero entonces tenías mal planteada la pregunta. Y lo de que los primeros deban ser bfill ¿es sólo porque no hay valor anterior sobre el que hacer ffill? ¿Si hubiera tal valor sería ffill para toda la columna?

Comment: De nuevo muchas gracias abulafia, me excuso por el mal entendido.  Yo tengo una serie de rendimiento de precios (dP/P) y quiero extraer el signo, con lo que explicas encontré la solución. Cuando el rendimiento es 0, la teoría dice que el signo debe ser el de la fila anterior y eso se soluciona con el método ffill. El problema aparece al comienzo de la serie, que siempre comienza con nan y puede pasar también que le sigan uno o varios 0, por lo que la anterior regla no aplicaria. Para solucionar eso apliqué luego el  método bfill, lo que me soluciona la asignación del nan y de 0s al comienzo.

Answer (score 0):

Con base en la respuesta de abulafia, hice el siguiente código que resuelve lo que necesito para mi función:

```
def desequilibrio(df,ret_columna):
    df[ret_columna] = df[ret_columna].apply(np.sign)
    df[ret_columna][df[ret_columna]==0] = np.nan
    df[ret_columna] = df[ret_columna].fillna(method='ffill')
    df[ret_columna] = df[ret_columna].fillna(method='bfill')
    return df
```